# Weird R problem: Internet keeps disconnecting whenever I run any raster calculation using the "raster" package

Tags: r, memory, r-raster, diskspace, internet-connection

I ran into what seems to be a fairly unique problem on R's "raster" package.

I am not sure how to provide a reproducible example for people reading this, but the long and short of it is that **whenever I perform calculations involving my raster objects, the internet shuts down for the whole house.** While I can't provide the raster images themselves because they are so big, I can provide their general description. Objects like these are about a gigabyte each.

```
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 15336, 19016, 291629376  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 30.85642, 30.85642  (x, y)
extent     : 610995.9, 1197762, 9526801, 10000015  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=52 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs  +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
source     : C:/Users/tug74077/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpcVf7pt/raster/r_tmp_2020-07-21_082952_22832_46671.grd
names      : layer 
values     : 6378.035, 2016403  (min, max)
```

And sometimes I use raster stacks, which are much larger (about 10 gigabytes)

```
class      : RasterStack 
dimensions : 15336, 19016, 291629376, 30  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 30.85642, 30.85642  (x, y)
extent     : 610995.9, 1197762, 9526801, 10000015  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=52 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
names      : ap_hp_stack.1, ap_hp_stack.2, ap_hp_stack.3, ap_hp_stack.4, ap_hp_stack.5, ap_hp_stack.6, ap_hp_stack.7, ap_hp_stack.8, ap_hp_stack.9, ap_hp_stack.10, ap_hp_stack.11, ap_hp_stack.12, ap_hp_stack.13, ap_hp_stack.14, ap_hp_stack.15, ... 
min values :     426.50653,     403.31589,     381.38617,    360.64886,     341.03912,     322.49561,     304.96039,     288.37863,     272.69846,      257.87088,      243.84953,      230.59058,      218.05255,      206.19627,      194.98465, ... 
max values :     134839.22,     127507.53,     120574.50,    114018.44,     107818.85,     101956.36,      96412.63,      91170.34,      86213.09,       81525.38,       77092.55,       72900.77,       68936.89,       65188.55,       61644.02, ...
```

The type of calculation that would disconnect the internet ranges from a simple stacking operation of 30 rasters like this:

```
ann.cost_hp_t_stack <- stack(ann.cost_hp_t)
```

(ann.cost_hp_t is a list of 30 rasters that look like a single raster layer in the above (former) description that will be stacked to create ann.cost_hp_t_stack, which resembles a raster stack in the above (latter) description),

to an operation that looks like this:

```
for (i in c(1:30)){
  ann.cost_hp_t[[i]] <- ann.cost_t_im / ((1 + 0.05)^i)
}
```

where ann.cost_t_im is another raster layer resembling the raster layer described above.

In addition to the internet cutting out for the whole router/house, my local disk gets filled up too, and I have to regularly restart R to free up about 140 gigabytes of disk space.

If you have read this far, thank you very much for your time. Also, sorry if the formatting is confusing.

TL;DR: My internet keeps cutting out when I use the "raster" package in R to create gigabytes upon gigabytes of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `raster` package does not use your network for normal computations (it only uses it to download data when you use the getData function). So it is directly related to that. It has to be related to what you computer does when files are created.

All I can think of is that you have a system that automatically copies your data to the cloud. So if you create a bunch of big files, that would slow down the Internet.

As for the filling up of your disk; that is because you are using very large files with functions that then need save these to disk (in a temp file). You can use other functions such as `calc` to use filenames. There would still be files, of course, but you may cut out intermediate files; if there are any. See `raster::removeTmpFiles` for removing them without exiting R.

Comment: The r-notebook file is in my dropbox folder, but my outputs from the writeRaster operations are saved in my local hard drive. 

Since R uses the folder that includes r-notebook as the work directory by default, do you think executing the lines from the r-notebook files cause temporary files to be stored in the dropbox folder?

As of now, I don't really see any additional files in there.

Comment: I think your temp folder is show in your question above, and you can also look at `tempdir()`. My suggestion is far-fetched, but is the best I could come up with. Perhaps you can shut down dropbox before you run the code as see if it helps. I am assuming that your computer is on wifi and that the house Internet does not depend on its CPU

Comment: By the way, thank you for making the raster package and all these different geospatial packages. I'm just getting into geography, and these packages have been incredibly helpful.